# why failed to embed custom python module in c++ func called by a cocoa app

Tags: python, c++, xcode, cocoa

I am trying embed custom python module in c++ func called by a cocoa app recently and get stuck in the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I created 2 projects using xcode, app1 & app2. The first one is an Command Line Tool app and the second one is a Cocoa app. Meanwhile, I created 2 .py file for them separately and get 2 folders look like below.

The code of the `BNRcallApp1.cpp` and the `BNRcallApp2.cpp` are basically the same and The 2 `.py` file are exactly the same, while the app1 works fine and the app2 keeps on yelling that there is a ModuleNotFoundError.

What am I missing here? Any help? Thanks a lot!

```
  ***Directory: 
          /Users/ABC/Desktop/app1
  ***app1's folder:
          ---app1
             ---BNRapp1.py
             ---BNRcallCPP.h
             ---BNRcallCPP.mm (objective-c call c++)
             ---BNRcallApp1.hpp
             ---BNRcallApp1.cpp (c++ call python module)
             ---...
          ---app1.xcodeproj

  ***Directory: 
          /Users/ABC/Desktop/app2
  ***app2's folder:
          ---app2
             ---BNRapp2.py
             ---BNRcallCPP.h
             ---BNRcallCPP.mm
             ---BNRcallApp2.hpp
             ---BNRcallApp2.cpp
             ---...
          ---app2.xcodeproj
          ---app2Tests
          ---app2UITests
```

I have already tried the following advices:

1. `sys.path.append` or `sys.path.insert`                ---doesn't work
2. add `__init__.py` to `app2` or `app2/app2` or both      ---doesn't work
3. add `.pth` with the content `/Users/ABC/Desktop/app2/app2` to the `/usr/local/ opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages`                                           ---doesn't work
4. copy the `BNRapp2.py` file to the folder `/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/ Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages`
                                                   ---doesn't work
5. copy the `BNRapp2.py` file to the folder `/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/ Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload` or `/usr/local/opt/ python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7`
                                                   ---work fine!

```
***BNRcallApp1.cpp:
       ...
       {
           Py_Initialize();
           if(Py_IsInitialized())
           {
               PyObject *pModule=NULL;
               PyObject *pFunc=NULL;
               PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
               PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('/Users/ABC/Desktop/app1/app1')");

               PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)");
               pModule=PyImport_ImportModule("BNRapp1");
               if(pModule)
               {
                   ...
               }
               else
               {
                   ...
               }
           }
           else
           {
               ...
           }
       }
       ...
```

```
***BNRcallApp2.cpp:
       ...
       {
           Py_Initialize();
           if(Py_IsInitialized())
           {
               PyObject *pModule=NULL;
               PyObject *pFunc=NULL;
               PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
               PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('/Users/ABC/Desktop/app2/app2')");

               PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)");
               pModule=PyImport_ImportModule("BNRapp2");
               if(pModule)
               {
                   ...
               }
               else
               {
                   ...
               }
           }
           else
           {
               ...
           }
       }
       ...
```

```
***BNRapp1.py & BNRapp2.py:       
       def feedback(user):
           return "hello!"
```

```
***Both the "print('sys.path')" command shows basically the same result:
['/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
'/Users/ABC/Desktop/app1/app1'] 
['/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
'/Users/ABC/Desktop/app2/app2']
```

I expect to import the python module in c++ by using the `sys.path.append`, but failed and got ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Please reformat your question, it is highly unreadable what you want

Comment: Oh, thanx for reminding : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out it is because of cocoa app's sandbox control. Turn it off and it will work fine. Or will need another method to work it out.